# python nltk module is creating it's own bugs

Tags: python, nltk

I have an error with nltk which doesn't allow me to open anymore my previous projects:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

example_sent = "This is a sample sentence, showing off the stop words filtration."

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_sent)

filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]

filtered_sentence = []

for w in word_tokens:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)

print(word_tokens)
print(filtered_sentence)
```

and when I run this I get this error

```
File "/Users/nicolas/Desktop/part 1 natural lenguage/stopwords.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 47, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, Counter
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 56, in <module>
    import sys, imp, os, re, types, inspect, __builtin__, pkgutil, warnings
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Users/nicolas/Desktop/part 1 natural lenguage/tokenize.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize.mwe      import MWETokenizer
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/mwe.py", line 31, in <module>
    from nltk.util import Trie
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, deque
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict
iMac-di-Monica:part 1 natural lenguage nicolas$
```

the error doesn't end here it also affect all my other projects with nltk and when I run this second code

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

EXAMPLE_TEXT = "Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weather is great, and Python is awesome. The sky is pinkish-blue. You shouldn't eat cardboard."

print(sent_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT))
print(word_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT))


for i in word_tokenize(EXAMPLE_TEXT) :
    print (i)
```

I get the same previous error, the second code worked perfectly before.

Comment: Did you perhaps make a script called `collections.py`? If so, you should rename it.

Comment: I guess it's `/Users/nicolas/Desktop/part 1 natural lenguage/tokenize.py`

Comment: What is your output of `import os; os.listdir()`?

Comment: my output of import os; os.listdir() is['.DS_Store', '.localized', 'Curse', 'EMAIL ARRIVO.py', 'My Games', 'Senza titolo.rtf', 'Senza titolofsd poy.rtf', 'Untitled.py', 'Untitledwiki1.py', 'Untitledwiki2.py']

Comment: i noticed one other thing while opwning this 2 files a new file show up called tokenize.pyc